# could not find test routes i made in my laravel request file when i run artisan route:list

Tags: laravel-5, wamp

i installed Laravel, made new controller and new request.I added a test routes in the request file but whenever i try to access it from the browser via Apache WAMP server it through NotFoundHttpException(1/1)

i tried modifying the Apache httpd.conf file 
AllowOverride ALL
Require all granted
i tried php artisan route:clear and route:cache
i tried to access the route through different URLs
public/home
public/index.php/home
not working 
however localhost/public loads laravel welcome page just fine
i opened config/app.php file and made sure that the RouteServiceProvider is included in the providers for the app
i opened RouteServiceProvider and the $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers'
but still when i type php artisan route:list i could not find them
i am trying for a day now can any one help

this is my request file

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class master extends FormRequest
{

    Route::get('/home','mastercontroller@index');
    Route::get('/lina','mastercontroller@index');
    Route::get('/love','mastercontroller@index');
    /**
    * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    /**
    * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

and this is my controller file

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class mastercontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
}
```

it should load the index view

Comment: Request Files is for validating inconming Requests...
Add Your routes to `web.php ` file

Comment: but is not that a temporary solution ??? does that mean that any route i put in the request won't work ???

Comment: Every route that ypu want to add to your app has to be on web.php file